# vue router doesn't works

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

When i click, it should route to `Brief.vue`
i wrote an p tag in Brief.vue file and also put a log `console.log('hello')`

when i click 약력(it means Brief career in korean),  it show me a log hello. but doesn't show a p tag

here is my Brief component

```
<template>
  <div class="brief">
    <h1>Biref</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
}
console.log('hello')
</script>
```

and below is a result of click

Comment: what css definition for class `brief` ?

Comment: i nothing didn't define any css. an example i learned, he defined class just for router. not for css

Comment: It's my fault haHa..... im very shame now. i didn't wrote router-view element.